# Visual Studio Code Track Changes

Tags: visual-studio-code

For all CSS, JavaScript and HTML modifications on pages that are handled through Visual Studio Code, is there a way to track changes?  I'm looking through the application settings, but failing to see anything OOTB that enables this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you integrate any version controlling tool (TFS, Git etc.) with VS Code, it starts to track changes on files.

Visual Studio Code version control [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol).