# Is there option to distinguish between saved and unsaved code in the Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a question that the Visual Studio Code has the option to distinguish between saved code and un-saved code.  Sometimes, I can't find the modified code in the editor window. So, I use "ctrl + z" to trace my modification.  Do you have your idea to trace your modification but not saved yet in the Visual Studio code?

Comment: Duplicate of this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445254/visual-studio-code-track-changes

Comment: related: [See unsaved changes in vscode](/q/65874120) (not a "passive" behaviour/decoration controlled by a setting, but something you can bring up manually)

Answer (score 1):

You always get a blue line (called gutter indicators ) on the left of unsaved code in the open editor,
NOTE:- if you are don't you can set them on as below

```
Goto
file > prefrences > settings  
search for "Scm Diff Decorations"
```

[image]

but if  it's not that helpful .

Having an auto save option turned on will be a great help.

```
File > Auto Save

or 
Goto 
file > prefrences > settings   
search for autosave
Turn it ON
```

Now after you saved you can have extensions like GIT  or source Control to show the changes made .

```
press ctrl + shift + G to open it
```

if not installed you can download it from

> EXTENSIONS : MARKETPLACE

```
ctrl + Shift + X

search for source control or  Git 
click on install
```

Comment: Thanks. I found autosave option and it's disabled. Is there an option to highlight modified code after the file open?

Comment: added the git option but you can also click on Green or Blue line beside the modified code to to display only modified code .

Comment: Could you see the blue or green line beside the modified code? I can't see that color. I use "One dark pro" theme.

Comment: goto "Scm Diff Decorations" in Scm Diff Decorations and turn them on it will be displayed

Comment: SCM:Diff Decorations  is  "all". But I can't  see different color beside modified code.

Comment: SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Visibility sset it to always

Comment: Yes. "SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Visibility" is always. But, I can't see decoration

Comment: both for user and Workspace ?

Comment: Yes, both are the same.

Comment: it seems to be strange to me , if possible try switching to standard theme and reloading VSCode

Comment: I will check it. I appreciate your kindness. Thank you.